# PHP Error Retrieving from database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to view my data in a database. My current code is below and the error I am getting is **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\viewnews.php on line 32** but it looks ok to me. Any help greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
<html>
  <Head>
    <Title> View News </Title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
    mysql_select_db('familease');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM news"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    print("<TABLE BORDER=1 WIDTH=\"75%\" CELLSPACING=2 CELLPADDING=2 ALIGN=CENTER>\N");
    print("<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>\n");
    print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>News Date</TD>\n");
    print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>News Description</TD>\n");
    print("</TR>\N");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
        print("<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>\n");
        print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>$Row[NewsDate]</TD>\n");
        print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>$Row[NewsDescription]</TD>\n");
        print("</TR>\N");

    mysql_close();
    print("</TABLE>\n"); 
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adobe Pagemill called and wants its uppercase HTML back... And this has NOTHING to do with SQL. It's purely a PHP syntax error.

Comment: Close your while loop bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should end head tag and While sentence:

```
 <head>
      <Title> View News </Title>
 </head> <!-- ADD THIS -->

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    print("<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>\n");
    print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>$Row[NewsDate]</TD>\n");
    print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>$Row[NewsDescription]</TD>\n");
    print("</TR>\N");
} // ADD THIS
```

Answer (score 2):

you have forgot to close the `while` loop :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   

  print("<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>\n");
  print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>$Row[NewsDate]</TD>\n");
  print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>$Row[NewsDescription]</TD>\n");
  print("</TR>\N");

}//add this
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<html>
  <Head>
    <Title> View News </Title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
    mysql_select_db('familease');

    $query = "SELECT * FROM news"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    print("<TABLE BORDER=1 WIDTH=\"75%\" CELLSPACING=2 CELLPADDING=2 ALIGN=CENTER>\N");
    print("<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>\n");
    print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>News Date</TD>\n");
    print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>News Description</TD>\n");
    print("</TR>\N");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
        print("<TR ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>\n");
        print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>$Row[NewsDate]</TD>\n");
        print("<TD ALIGN=CENTER VALIGN=TOP>$Row[NewsDescription]</TD>\n");
        print("</TR>\N");
    }
    mysql_close();
    print("</TABLE>\n"); 
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```